# CakePHP custom field not passed by paginator

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have this method in my `PhotoalbumsModel`

```
public function index_list()
{
    $data = $this->find()
    ->contain(['Images' => function($q) {
            $q->select([
                 'total' => $q->func()->count('image_id')
            ])
            ->group(['photoalbum_id']);
            return $q;
        }
    ]);

    foreach ($data as $row)
    {
        $row->image_count = 0;
        if (isset($row->images{0}->total))
        {
            $row->image_count = $row->images{0}->total;
        }
        unset($row->images);
    }       
    return $data;
}
```

Which basicaly adds `image_count` to the rows.

In my controller I use:

```
<?php
class PhotoalbumsController extends AppController
{
    public $paginate = [
        'limit' => 2,
        'order' => ['id' => 'desc']
    ];

    public function index()
    {
        $photoalbums = $this->paginate($this->Photoalbums->index_list());
        $this->set(compact('photoalbums'));
    }
```

However, in my view `image_count` isn't passed. Without using the Paginator it is passed.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paginator applies options to the query, such as the limit, which will cause the query to be marked as dirty, which in turn clears any possibly buffered resultsets, so what you are doing there is iterating over a to be dropped result set, and modifying objects (entities) that will descend into nowhere.

You shouldn't rely on buffered result sets at all, if you need to reliably modify the results of a query, then you should use a result formatter or map/reduce, which is both applied on the results everytime the query is being executed:

```
$query = $this
    ->find()
    ->contain([
        'Images' => function($q) {
            $q
                ->select([
                    'total' => $q->func()->count('image_id')
                ])
                ->group(['photoalbum_id']);

            return $q;
        }
    ])
    ->formatResults(function (\Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface $results) {
        return $results->map(function ($row) {
            $row['image_count'] = $row['images'][0]['total'];

            return $row;
        });
    });

return $query;
```

That being said, you could also handle this directly on SQL level by joining the association instead of containing it, and selecting the column in the main query:

```
$query = $this->find();
$query
    ->select(['image_count' => $query->func()->count('Images.id')])
    ->enableAutoFields()
    ->leftJoinWith('Images')
    ->group('Photoalbums.id');
```

And there's of course also the counter cache behavior.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Adding Calculated Fields](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-calculated-fields)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Modifying Results with Map/Reduce](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#modifying-results-with-map-reduce)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using leftJoinWith](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-leftjoinwith)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Behaviors > CounterCache](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html)**

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer! I will test it as soon as Im home. I did see the counter cache functionality, but didnt get it to work with link and unlink the data.